# Stuck on a polar coordinates integral calculus question

Tags: calculus

> Once every century the Klingon moon Bosok completely eclipses the moon
> Yan-ki. As seen from the city Mitek, the two moons appear as circular
> discs, with radii respectively $\sqrt{2},1$ (unit: dorks). When the
> center of Bosok is exactly on the circumference of Yan-ki, the problem
> is to find the area (in square dorks) of the region of the Yan-ki disc
> that is not yet covered. Draw a diagram in polar coordinates, placing
> the center of Bosok at the origin, and the other center on the
> positive x-axis. Set up a definite integral representing the area of
> the desired region. Indicate how the significant limit on the integral
> was determined.

Here is what I figured out. When the center of Bosok is on the circumference of Yan-ki, the triangle formed by the center of Bosok, the center of Yanki, and the intersection point on the circumference of Bosok has a pi/4 angle (because $1^2+1^2=\sqrt{2}^2$). But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Edit: So I wrote the circles in terms of polar coordinates. For the circle centered at the origin I got x = $\sqrt2$cos$\theta$, y = $\sqrt2$sin$\theta$, and for the off-centered one I got x = 1+ cos$\theta$, y = sin$\theta$. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes you found the angles correct. It is from $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Write the equation of both circles first and draw a diagram. Identify the region you need to find area of. Substitute $x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$. Then you can find $r$ for both circles. For the circle centered at the origin, it is straightforward. For the circle centered at $(1, 0)$, you will get $r$ in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: Please edit your post with your work if you get stuck.

Comment: @MathLover So I drew a diagram and wrote the equations in polar coordinates but I'm not sure how to express the region I need to find the area of in actual equations.

Comment: You need to find area so $r$ cannot be constant as you need interior points too. So you should use substitution as I mentioned in my comments. What is the equation of the second circle you have?

Comment: If you use $x = r \cos\theta$ for one and $x = 1 + r\cos\theta$ for the other, you will have more difficult time computing. So please use $x = r \cos\theta$ in both cases. Circle centered at the origin is ok. You want area outside it, right? So you know $r \geq \sqrt2$. You need to now find upper bound of $r$ which will come from the second circle.

Comment: For second circle, $(x-1)^2+y^2 = 1 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 2x$. Now if you use the substitution I mentioned, you get $r = 2 \cos\theta$ and that is the upper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So is the answer 2* $\frac{1}{2}$ * $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (2cos\theta)^2 - 2 \,d\theta$?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bosok is at the origin, its equation in polar coordinates is $r=\sqrt{2}$. Yan-ki has the equation $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, so if we let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, we get

$$r^2\cos^2\theta-2r\cos\theta+1+r^2\sin^2\theta=1$$

$$r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=2r\cos\theta$$

$$r=2\cos\theta$$

as the polar equation for Yan-ki.

We are trying to find the area to the right of Bosok and the left of Yan-ki, so we have

$$\sqrt{2}<r<2\cos\theta$$

and as you correctly pointed out,

$$-\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

So you now have the bounds on $r$ and the bounds on $\theta$, which should allow you to find the desired area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So is the answer 2* $\frac{1}{2}$ * $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (2cos\theta)^2 - 2 \,d\theta$?